# finding the Postion on element in code behind

Tags: c#

I want to find the absolute position and parent control from code behind in c sharp...

Comment: "absolute position and parent control" of *what*?

Comment: Do you mean like x,y coordinates of winform controls? html/css positioning of controls on a webpage? ...?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms or WPF:

```
var screenPos = myControl.PointToScreen(new Point(0,0));
var parentControl = myControl.Parent as Control;
```